# How to filter insert html from some tags (contenteditable)

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, contenteditable, onpaste

I have a tag div with an `contenteditable = true` attribute.When Paste events happen I want to filter pasted html from some tags.How can i do this ?

Comment: I've added an answer. Your questing is not that detailed, if you are looking to get the content of the paste event, and check the content in order to determine if you should prevent this event (stop the content being added to the `<div>`) or not. Let me know and I will show you a way of doing that as well.

Comment: @Titus here is my example `onPaste = {(e) => {
             e.preventDefault ();

             e.currentTarget.innerHTML = e.clipboardData
               .getData ("text / html")
               .replace (/ (<\ /? (?: span | div) [^>] *>) | <[^>] +> / gi, "$ 1");
           }} `

but in this case i am losing the cursor locations

Comment: If I get this right, you want to remove opening and closing `div` and `span` tags from the pasted text.

Comment: @Titus i remove all tags except div and span

Comment: @Pranvera_leva Have you tried my answer? It's the most concise solution to this problem.

Comment: @Spectric Well, if you give an example for react, then I'll try.but I'm not sure if this will work.

Answer (score 2):

Listen for the `paste` event and assign the `textContent` to the `innerHTML`. Thanks to the nature of `textContent`, HTML tags are removed but the output in text is preserved.

We use `setTimeout` in the event listener to account for the fact that the `paste` event handler is fired before the content is updated.

```js
document.querySelector('div').addEventListener('paste', function() {
  setTimeout(() => {
    this.innerHTML = this.textContent;
  }, 0);
})
```

```html
<div contenteditable="true">

</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can just query the `div` for specific elements. Here is an example:

```js
const div = document.querySelector('div')
div.addEventListener('paste', e => {
  setTimeout(() => {
    const elements = getTags('strong');
    console.log('@the paste event, tags count: ', elements.length);
  }, 0);
});

function getTags(tagName) {
  return [...div.querySelectorAll(tagName)];
}

console.log('tags count: ', getTags('strong').length);
```

```html
<div contenteditable="true" style="border 1px solid black; width: 200px; height: 200px">
  <strong>Some </strong><span>thing </span><strong>for </strong><span>testing</span>
</div>
```

The `getTags` function just query the `contenteditable` `<div>` for elements that have a specific tag name.
I've filled this `<div>` with some content by default to show this working without using the `paste` event.

Also, in the `paste` event listener I've used `setTimeout` to make sure the DOM is updated with the new elements before trying to get the element's we are interested in.